# alernative to normalize() for sorting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, normalize

I have an application that is sorting an array of speakers alphabetically. Some of the names of the speakers have special characters such as "Álvaro" on the first letter.

I was able to get it to work using `normalize()` as illustrated below

```
filteredData = filteredData.sort((a,b)=>{

        a = a.name.normalize('NFD')
        b = b.name.normalize('NFD')

        if(a < b){
            return -1
        }
        if(a >b){
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    })
```

However, much to my dismay i found out that IE is not reeading that properly. I had the same issue with `.find()` but i found a simple polyfill that fixed it very quickly. I haven't found a good polyfill i can just plug in to fix `normalize()`.

Could i use a alternative to `normalize()` or does anyone know of a legit good polyfill for this method?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `String.localeCompare` for the sort?

Comment: hmm i didnt know about this method. Will look into it now thanks. How would you use it along with the sort() method?

Comment: I posted an example in an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localeCompare` is typically used for sorting strings. It has [lots of options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for localization or sorting numbers and it's supported by IE:

```js
let names = [
    'Álvaro',
    'AArdvark',
    'Mark',
    'Álmaro',
    "Alvaro",
    "Áavaro"
]
console.log(names.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)))
```